# How to set Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there other way to set "Disable options to download, print, and copy for commenters and viewers" in google app script? I searched hard and no solutions found. My previous problem is the "Prevent editors from changing access and adding new people" and it solve already.

I tried to use file.setViewersCanCopyContent(false); base on what is searched but this one is not working. I tried this one but didn't work also

```
var labels = {
    'labels': {restricted: true}
  };
  Drive.Files.update(labels, fileId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

You can set `copyRequiresWriterPermission` property of the drive file to `true`.

#### Snippet:

```
 Drive.Files.patch({copyRequiresWriterPermission:true}, fileId);
```

#### Reference:

- [Drive#File#patch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/patch)

Comment: Thanks it works! And also i changed my Drive into v2

Comment: @Newb How did you change? Apps script only supports v2

Comment: from Advanced Google Services > Drive API (options v3/v2)